# How is the iOS App Store Updates list organized?

Tags: ios-appstore, software-update, sort

I have dozens of apps in my iOS App Store that have updates available, but I have no interest in updating most of them. There are certain apps though that if an update were available I would want to install it. But I can't find any rhyme or reason to how the updates are sorted in that section of the App Store app which makes it harder for me to see if something is available short of slowly scrolling through the whole list or searching for that app directly.

So how are they organized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to say it's random. I've tried looking at it across various ways it could be sorted, there's no organization. I've updated all apps and watched new updates come in, and when another app has a new update available, there is no way to predict where in the list of updates it will show up.

However, in the updates section for iOS apps in iTunes, they appear to be sorted alphabetically with sort options. Hopefully that will be extended to iOS in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be flippant but I don't think anyone outside of **Apple** knows.  I've had Apple products for years and my only guess is they're rolled out within a specific time after their review has completed.  We don't know when the apps are reviewed, except for our own, so we don't know how we stack-up against the other apps that have been updated.

Comment: Not sure you understood my question. How are the list of available updates in the iOS App Store sorted? Let's say I go to the updates tab and it says Pandora, Waze, and Google Maps. Which one will be on top? The most popular app? The one most recently updated? The one I use the most? The one I've updated longest ago? Alphabetically? Date originally created?

Comment: I'm trying to think of all sorts of factors but cannot find any pattern and kind of think they are placed randomly. Which is annoying because I'd like to be able to know where within a long list to look for one specific app.

Comment: I think I understood what you were looking for and my answer still stands. There is no obvious way of determining what order the updates will be displayed to you.

Comment: What does being rolled out after their review have to do with anything?

Comment: The app update that's approved first gets released to the store first. The other apps that are reviewed after that are released, too. When your i-device polls the App Store for updates, *maybe* the app that was released first will be the first app you see on the **Updates** tab.

Comment: There are apps that I have that I haven't updated for a long time, and then there's an app I updated a couple days ago with a new update available yet it shows up between those older apps. So I don't think that is it. Random may be the best answer.

Comment: That was my answer: we don't know, only Apple knows. I had a guess based on my experiences (and I indicated it was a guess).

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. I was confused because the answer you have seemed to go on about irrelevant details about how apps get reviewed and didn't explicitly say that your guess was that they're organized by the date the app's review has finished. Which again based on my experience would be wrong anyway. Thanks anyhow, didn't mean to sound ungrateful for your input.